# Error code 1062 sql

Tags: mysql

I'm getting the error

> code 1062 in the INSERT code below (for the table 'Tech').

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tech` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES AppliedTech(id_questions)
) ENGINE=InnoDB   DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `Tech` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Applied Tech'),
(2, 'Communications Equipment'),
(3, 'Computer Systems'),
(4, 'Internet/Digital Media'),
(5, 'Semiconductors'),
(6, 'IT Services'),
(7, 'Payments Processing'),
(8, 'Software');
```

Answer (score 0):

its seems you facing duplicate keys in the other table AppliedTech

Comment: I think you're right! How do I fix that problem...CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AppliedTech` (
  `id_question` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `questions` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `questionid` int(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_question`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB   DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6;

Comment: the auto increment start with 6 ?? it should start 1 as the values in the tech table , second thing you can disable mysql foreign key checks before you import or create tables 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
create the two tables then enable the foreign key checks 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

Answer (score 0):

The table `Tech` already exists and has data. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` don't re-create table and in insert you have duplicate key violation.